# One Xpath expression doesn't work in selenium, but works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have one question about xpath.
There is td like this in chrome:

```
<td class="dataCol col02">
"Hello world(notes:there is$)nbsp;"
<a href="xxxx">[View Hierarchy]</a>
</td>
```

but when I inspect the same element in Firefox it doesn't have $nbsp and double quotes;

```
<td class="dataCol col02">
Hello world
<a href="xxxx">[View Hierarchy]</a>
</td>
```

I used FireFinder and use the xpath:

```
//td[text()='Hello world']
```

, it can locate that element.

but when I use selenium api 2.24, it couldn't find that element.

```
by.xpath("//td[text()='Hello world']")
```

Do you have any idea of that?
Thanks!

Comment: do you mean there is a space or the `&nbsp;` entity?

Comment: BTW, check the source (<kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>) not the DOM display by inspector such as Chrome `devTools` and `Firebug` as they are _edited_ version of the source

Comment: If the element is in an `iframe`, you must use `driver.switchTo().frame()` before selecting elements within.

Answer (score 7):

Try with `normalize-space()` which trims leading and trailing whitespace characters:

```
//td[normalize-space(text())='Hello world']
```

---

Edit following the different comments:

here's an XPath expression that's probably better suited in the general case:

```
//td[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'Hello world')]
```

meaning it matches `<td>` nodes if the concatenated string content of the whole `<td>`, less leading and trailing whitespace, starts with "Hello world"

Comment: Add this also - `//td[normalize-space(.)='Hello world']` .. :)

Comment: I don't think so @Babai, `//td[normalize-space(.)='Hello world']` will also include the "[View Hierarchy]" string in the test, so it won't match. `//td[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'Hello world')]` works though

Comment: I just wanted to tell you,that `text()` no needed. only `.` will work.. And the solution I am demanding here is the more compact version of your answer. That's it. `//td[normalize-space(text())='Hello world']` could be written as `//td[normalize-space(.)='Hello world']`. that's it. :) :D

Comment: I agree `text()` is usually not needed for a number of use cases you find on SO. But `.` and `text()` are not equivalent in this context: `.` is the current node, in this case `<td class="dataCol col02">
Hello world
<a href="xxxx">[View Hierarchy]</a>
</td>`; the `<td>` has 2 nodes, 1 text node containing "Hello world" and 1 `<a>` node. `text()` selects only text nodes. You can test out the different expressions in http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Ohh!! I see.. :) get it now.. :)

Comment: FYI, `text()` matches **a single** text node.  So while this answer is correct for this specific example, it would not work with something like `<td>Hello <a href="xxxx">link</a> world</td>`, because that has two text nodes: "Hello " and " world".

Comment: Thank you @RossPatterson, I agree. I would have suggested `//td[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'Hello world')]` but preferred to stick with OP's exact match test

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone! But I tried all the options, it still can't find the element. Do you know whether it is because of selenium api? I have no clue about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `contains()` function.
Your xpath will look like: `//td[contains(text(),'Hello world')]`